# Using T -test results to find probability of an event occurring

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, t-test, negative-binomial-distribution, prediction-interval

Given two samples, one consisting of a different number of times someone made sales calls to different potential clients who ended up buying the product. the other one consists of a different number of times someone made sales calls to different potential clients who ended up **NOT buying** the product.

Any idea if possible how I can find the maximum number of calls the salesperson needs to make before giving up?

I did a t-test and below are the results.

Group One (bought): Mean  4.40897500, SD 4.15437900, SEM 0.12088744, N  1181.

Group Two (didn't buy): 
Mean 3.23937500,
SD2.80748100,
SEM 0.02661269,
N 11129.

P value is less than 0.0001
t = 12.8971
df = 12308

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site.

A $t$-test is a test for a difference in means. You current setup does not answer your question, it will only tell you if there is a significant difference between the mean number of calls of the group that ended up buying the product and the mean number of calls of the calls of the group that did not.

What you should do instead is make a prediction interval for the number of calls until a product is bought. The number of calls until success can be considered a negative binomial process.

There is a complication, however: Can you assume that customers who did not buy the product *never would have*, regardless of the number of calls? If the answer is yes, you can simply fit a negative binomial distribution to the subset of customers who ended up buying the product. If the answer is no, however, the resulting prediction interval will underestimate the number of calls until success, because you have a selection bias towards those who bought the product in under $X$ calls.

This does not seem like a trivial problem, and it is certainly not something you can estimate from the results of a $t$-test, so I would recommend hiring a statistical consultant.